# Official Airflow Docker image does not recognise airflow command

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, airflow

I have pulled and ran the `apache/airflow:python3.8-master` image. When calling `airflow` in the bash terminal, I am told it is not recognised.

However, if I use the (older) `apache/airflow:2.0.1` image, the `ariflow` command works fine.

The official Airflow [docker-compose.yaml](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/docker-compose.yaml) example suggests that the default value for `AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME` has been set to `apache/airflow:python3.8-master`. However, it has actually been set to `apache/airflow:2.0.1`.

Has anyone successfully used the `apache/airflow:python3.8-master` to build run Airflow?

Comment: seems like its `apache/airflow:master-python3.8` and not `apache/airflow:python3.8-master`

Comment: After testing I can confirm this is correct. Strange that the .yaml references the wrong image